# Custom call to `makeindex` using Auctex

Tags: auctex

Following one of the answers from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472/how-can-i-have-two-or-more-distinct-indexes/289540#289540) for managing two distinct indexes, I need to call

```
makeindex -t mydoc.plg -o mydoc.pnd mydoc.pdx
makeindex -t mydoc.slg -o mydoc.snd mydoc.sdx
```

when I want to update my indexes. How can I tell Auctex to call these two lines in an automatic way? Should I do something like "override" the Index command from Auctex?

Comment: Just notes from an analysis for a general approach: `(TeX-add-style-hook "index"...)`  Therein: Add parsing `newindex` macros to `LaTeX-auto-regexp-list`. One gets a list of the new indexes. Substitute`TeX-run-index` by an alternative `my-TeX-run-indexes` in `TeX-command-list` (e.g., via customization). In `my-TeX-run-indexes` do essentially the stuff of `TeX-run-index` for all indexes found via the list of indexes generated by the new entry in `LaTeX-auto-regexp-list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most simple solution is to change the `Command` part of the `Index` entry in `TeX-command-list` via <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `TeX-command-list` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

I suggest to input

```
makeindex -t %s.plg -o %s.pnd %s.pdx; makeindex -t %s.slg -o %s.snd %s.sdx;
```

there. Afterwards click the button `Apply`.

This works but it has the disadvantage that you must repeat the setting after the next restart of Emacs.

Alternatively you can change the value of `TeX-command-list` buffer-locally with file local variables in the LaTeX file. That is demonstrated with the file-local variables in the next example. The LaTeX part is stolen from [Gilles' answer on tex.se](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/289540/44136).

One must take care that the modification of `TeX-command-list` remains buffer local. That makes the form after the `;;; eval:` a bit complicated.

Nevertheless you find the above `makeindex` command line in there and you can modify according to your needs.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{index}
\newindex{person}{pdx}{pnd}{Index of named persons}
\newindex{symbol}{sdx}{snd}{Index of symbolism}

\begin{document}

Hello, \index*[person]{vanden} \index*[symbol]{SomeSymbol}.

\printindex[person]
\printindex[symbol]
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% eval: (setcar (or (cl-member "Index" (setq-local TeX-command-list (copy-list TeX-command-list)) :key #'car :test #'string-equal) (setq-local TeX-command-list (cons nil TeX-command-list))) '("Index" "makeindex -t %s.plg -o %s.pnd %s.pdx; makeindex -t %s.slg -o %s.snd %s.sdx;" TeX-run-index nil t :help "makeindex for index.sty"))
%%% End:
```

There are several alternatives for the form in `%%% eval: ...`. They all have their pros and cons.

1. Using `copy-alist`

```el
(setf (alist-get "Index" (setq-local mylist (copy-alist TeX-command-list)) nil nil #'string-equal) '("makeindex -t %s.plg -o %s.pnd %s.pdx; makeindex -t %s.slg -o %s.snd %s.sdx;" TeX-run-index nil t :help "makeindex for index.sty"))
```

PROS:

- somewhat shorter
- Just calls to `setf`, `alist-get`, and `copy-alist`

CONS:

- all `cons` are copied not just the modified ones

---

2. Defining a new function in your init file

```el
(defun modified-alist (alist &optional modifications &rest plist)
  "Make a copy of ALIST and apply MODIFICATIONS.
The entries of the association list MODIFICATIONS replace the
corresponding entries of ALIST.
\nKeywords supported:  :test :test-not :key

\n(fn ALIST &optional MODIFICATIONS [KEYWORD VALUE]...)"
  (setq alist (cl-copy-list alist))
  (dolist (m modifications)
    (setcar (or (apply #'cl-member (car m) alist plist) (setq alist (cons nil alist))) m))
  alist)
```

You can use that function in the `;;; eval:...` line:

```el
(setq-local TeX-command-list (modified-alist TeX-command-list '(("Index" "makeindex -t %s.plg -o %s.pnd %s.pdx; makeindex -t %s.slg -o %s.snd %s.sdx;" TeX-run-index nil t :help "makeindex for index.sty")) :key #'car :test #'string-equal)
```

PROS:

- including the `setq-local` just two commands
- only the modified cons is copied

CONS:

- requires code in init file

Comment: Mmmmm... I tried the first approach (the one using the eval) and it does not work for me. I see only one of the two indexes. Do I need to put that code in the master file or also in the others? Does the code work for you (can you see two indexes)? I am afraid that the problem is not your code but the usage of the two indexes as described in the linked question. I will make some more trials and update you

Comment: It works from the command line, so the solution using `eval` is for some reason not working with me. Do I need to tell Emacs that I have changed the `eval` field?

Comment: @Nisba Yes, kill the buffer and find the file again. Emacs will ask you whether to eval the eval forms in the file local variables. Answer `yes` or `t` to that question. Alternatively you can also call `M-: (hack-local-variables)`.`RET`. In that case there is no need to re-load the file.

Comment: I have done as you said but Emacs does not ask me to eval the local variables. I also see that changing the `TeX-master` field has no effect. So the problem could be with my Emacs. I will come back to this answer when I will have fixed my Emacs, for the moment I give you the upvote ;-)

Comment: What does `C-h v enable-local-variables RET` say? It should be `t`. What happens if you call `M-x normal-mode RET`.

Comment: Wonderful! By calling `normal-mode` I caught an error due to a wrong configuration I wrote. That code was breaking the loading of the functions invoked when entering the `LaTeX-mode-hook`. Fixing the faulty configuration your code works (and it gets updated when I kill and reload the file, or I press `C-x C-v`). Just for completeness, the faulty code was `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (setq fill-column 10000))` in my `user-config` (I use Spacemacs); placing the `setq` within a lambda fixed the code.